# .done does not update button value

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.msg-buttons :button').on("click",function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-rel");

        $.get( "account/process-actions.php", { value: id } )
            .done(function( data ) {
                $(this).attr('value', data);
                //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            });
    });
});
```

I want to update the value of a button after I have the button change a value in the db (there is a group of buttons).

The problem with the above is that .done does not seem to allow the "this". It does post back the data, and the alert works too.

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the done handler does not refer to the clicked button.

Solution 1. Use a closure variable

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.msg-buttons :button').on("click", function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-rel");

        var $this = $(this);
        $.get("account/process-actions.php", {
            value: id
        }).done(function (data) {
            $this.attr('value', data);
            //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
    });
});
```

Solution 2: Use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom execution context to the callback method

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.msg-buttons :button').on("click", function (event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-rel");

        $.get("account/process-actions.php", {
            value: id
        }).done($.proxy(function (data) {
            $(this).attr('value', data);
            //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        }, this));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you reference `this` inside of the `done` function, it won't work as intended since `this` is now in a different scope than in the `$('.msg-buttons :button')` function. If you make a variable to reference it, it should work. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.msg-buttons :button').on("click",function(event) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-rel");
        var self = this;

        $.get( "account/process-actions.php", { value: id } )
            .done(function( data ) {
                $(self).attr('value', data);
                //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have store the this context in the variable and use that variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.msg-buttons :button').on("click",function(event) {
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.attr("data-rel");

    $.get( "account/process-actions.php", { value: id } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            that.attr('value', data);
            //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
        });
});
});
```

hope this helps.